# Windows 10 issues

Tags: windows-10

After updating I have some critical issues on Windows 10 Home:

- Start menu and cortana are not working. Start menu does not open when I left click and cortana seems freeze since I cannot type anything.
- Microsoft Edge opens and closes inmediately.
- Tray icons do not work, I mean, I cannot do left-click on them, it does not work, only right-click works. For example, If I left-click on volumne icon nothing happens so I cannot change volume level. Also, If I left-click on WiFi, nothing happens, the menu with the list of available WiFi does not open. Also Notificactions window does not open when I left-click on it.

  - My Internet connection does not work on Edge and Chrome, it only works on firefox.

I have done a lot of things commented in the web, but nothing works.

List of things I have done without success:

- Repair cortana using:

  Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
- Create a new user account
- Rebuild indexing through indexing options in control panel as said [here](https://mspoweruser.com/search-not-working-windows-10-heres-fix/)
- Booting to Safe Mode, and then immediately booting back into normal mode.
- Executing commands specified [here](http://Dism%20/Online%20/Cleanup-Image%20/RestoreHealth)
- Run the troubleshooter explained [here](http://lifehacker.com/microsofts-start-menu-repair-tool-fixes-common-windows-1782496302)
- Register start menu as explained [here](https://www.kapilarya.com/re-register-start-menu-windows-10)
- Follow all the steps indicated [here](https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-microsoft-windows-shellexperiencehost-and-microsoft-windows-cortana-applications-need-to-be-installed-correctly-windows-10)

So any ideas?

Comment: In safe mode everything was working normally?

Comment: look if you see shellexperiencehost.exe crashes in eventlog. if you see crashes, create a crash dump http://pastebin.com/tU3Agf5M and share (onedrive share link) the compressed dmp file.

Comment: @vembutech in safe mode it is not working.

Comment: @magicandre1981 eventlog says: Activation of app Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy!App failed with error: The app didn't start. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Comment: have you done what is written there? Have you checked this event log entry for me details?